# Swift - Automatic Caluclation

Tags: swift, swift3, calculator

I am currently building a calculator app with swift.
I want the calculation to be automatic instead of me pressing = button.
EQLabel is where i want the calculation to be
and inputLabel is where the user can see there equation for example 1 + 5 
Below is my calculator code.

```
// Start of Calculator
@IBOutlet weak var EQLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UITextField!

var numberOnScreen = 0;
var previousNumber = 0;
var performingMath = false
var operation = 0;

@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if performingMath == true {
        inputLabel.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(Double(inputLabel.text!)!)
        performingMath = false
    }
    else {
        inputLabel.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(Double(inputLabel.text!)!)
    }
}

@IBAction func multiButtons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if inputLabel.text != "" && sender.tag != 15 {
        previousNumber = Int(Double(inputLabel.text!)!)
        // Plus
        if sender.tag == 11 {
             inputLabel.text! = "+"
        }
        // Times
        if sender.tag == 12 {
             inputLabel.text = "x"
        }
        // Minus
        if sender.tag == 13 {
             inputLabel.text = "-"
        }
        // Divide
        if sender.tag == 14 {
             inputLabel.text = "/"
        }

        operation = sender.tag
        performingMath = true
    }
    else if sender.tag == 15 {
        if operation == 11 {
            EQLabel.text = String(previousNumber + numberOnScreen)
        }
        if operation == 12 {
           EQLabel.text = String(previousNumber * numberOnScreen)
        }
        if operation == 13 {
            EQLabel.text = String(previousNumber - numberOnScreen)
        }
        if operation == 14 {
            EQLabel.text = String(previousNumber / numberOnScreen)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. Should do exactly what you want.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
   }

    func calculateTotal() {
       let totalInt = Int(firstTextField.text!) + Int(secondTextField.text!)
       totalLabel.text = String(totalInt)
    }
```

Do let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: So to make sure, it would be like this?
override func viewDidLoad() {
       inputlabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
   }

    func calculateTotal() {
       let totalInt = Int(inputlabel.text!) + Int(EQlabel.text!)
       inputlabel.text = String(totalInt)
    }

Comment: I have put the ViewDidLoad code in but coming up with an error saying.
Value of type 'viewcontroller' has no member 'calculateTotal' 
I have put the func CalculateTotal in.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late response.
I think you have made a mistake of capitalizing the first letter of the function. At least thats what you typed

Comment: Also, just a tip, if you want it to auto calculate for both text fields, do the same for both. 

EQLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

and 

inputLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged) 

Also, make sure you make it a number keyboard to avoid crashes. :)

Comment: Also, you should really change your naming for a text field to eqTextField and inputTextField as it is very bad practice.

Comment: Hmmm. Would you like to copy paste your code? Maybe I can figure out whats going from? Or just share a repo which i'll download.

Comment: Here is the code, I have had to change it a little bit .http://pastebin.com/UVDXYy6q

Comment: Hi. 
I noticed you have written 
        outputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), for: UIControlEvents) instead of 
        outputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged). You forgot the"EditingChanged"

Comment: hey, I have created a project for you. you can take a look at it. https://github.com/clintongwen/testForGeorge

Comment: Cool thank you, I will have a look later, then I will let you know cheers :)

Comment: How do I add a var to the .addtarget?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `addTarget` on your button. But your calculator needs to know when you have finished typing in the second number, unless you are only using numbers of a certain length?. If you want it to update the answer as  you type id go with something like.

```
inputLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourCaculateMethod), for: .editingChanged)
```

then have your `equalsLabel.text` equal the result. this will update it as you go.

Id think about naming your `inputLabel` to `inputTextField` too as its a little missleading